# Should I wrap launching a python process in another executable?

Tags: asp.net, python, security

So I have a 3rd party application which exposes a Python API.  I have a python script that does what I need it to do with that 3rd party application.

The python script only uses command line arguments, no user input and writes to stdout.

I'm wiring this up to be launched at runtime from an ASP.NET website.  Since python is so powerful, I'm wondering if it would make sense from a security standpoint to create a new executable that launches the python process with a hard coded or locally read (App.Config) script path and copy its command line arguments to the python process.

This new executable would be launched from the .NET application as a way to prevent attackers from uploading and launching arbitrary python code?  Does this negate any attack vectors or is it just extra complexity?

Also, I can't use IronPython, as the 3rd party extensions are written for CPython only.

Idea of the code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "goodscript.py \"" + argument1.Replace("\"","\\\"") + "\" \"" +
  argument2.Replace("\"","\\\"") + "\"";
p.Start();
```

I'm worried that either a command line switch like -i could be injected or that somehow the file path to goodscript.py could be changed to point to another script.  I guess if the later is possible then really the file path to python.exe could be changed to another executable file path.

Comment: We'd need to see the actual code to say for sure, but it sounds like it's just extra complexity.

Comment: @thepaul I've added some code for clarification

Comment: After attempting several tries at user data like hi\"; cmd or hi\" | cmd, it seems all arguments are sent to python.exe rather than evaluated on the command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code definitely has security concerns. I'm not sure how Process.StartInfo works there; if it splits up the arguments before executing the subprocess or if it uses some shell to do it for you, but either way, there's at least room for an attacker to put backslashes in the argument strings and trick your double-quote-escaping.

If you have some other method to convey arguments individually, instead of trying to pack them into a string and let something else parse them apart, that would be much preferable.

Comment: I attempted variations like hi\"; cmd or hi\" | cmd or hi\\"& cmd but it all only seems to go to python rather then act like a pure shell command would, any ideas on how else to break the argument strings?

Comment: Yeah, if it's not being interpreted by a shell, then there probably isn't a danger of other commands being invoked that way, and that's good. On the other hand, without knowing what rules *are* in play, it's hard to say for sure what the dangers are. And for sure there's still a potential for an attacker to change how the arguments are separated, introduce additional arguments, etc. That may not be a problem in your case, but then again it might, even if it doesn't seem like it. These things can be real subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python script is going to be invoked by the website. If someone can use the website to cause the Python script to be invoked with different arguments, or to execute a different script, or whatever, then **that's** the security hole. It has nothing to do with "Python being so powerful", this would be a security issue for calling out to **any** language

How exactly do you think this would be affected by wrapping the Python script with something else and invoking that instead? Either someone can cause a different executable to be invoked, or to be invoked with different arguments or on different data, in which case you're screwed no matter what language you're calling. Or they can't, in which case you're fine no matter what language you're calling.

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands, your script is not just an added complexity, but is actually opening up a security hole. Namely, that you're passing the arguments a single string that have to be parsed instead of as pre-tokenized list of strings.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you pass arguments as a list of strings in .NET?

Comment: No idea how to do it in .NET, but POSIX defined the exec family of functions, which is also available in Windows by including process.h